# Inserting INTO a Table with VARRAY Type data type column from a SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

TYPE `emp_varray_typ` created as below:

```
CREATE TYPE emp_varray_typ AS VARRAY(50) OF VARCHAR2(25);
```

Table DEPT_ARRAY created as
CREATE TABLE dept (DEPT_NO NUMBER, EMP_NM_ARRAY emp_varray_typ);

EMPLOYEE table as below:

```
**DEPT_NO | EMP_NM**
  10      | Scot
  10      | Tiger
  10      | John
  20      | Cindy
  20      | Rock
```

Want to insert data from `EMPLOYEE` table into `DEPT_ARRAY` table as 2 records (`EMP_NM` as an array into `EMP_NM_ARRAY`), like

```
**DEPT_NO | EMP_NM_ARRAY**
10      | {Scot, Tiger, John}
20      | {Cindy, Rock}
```

Is there a way to insert by using SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLLECT.html#GUID-A0A74602-2A97-449B-A3EC-847D38D3DA90) aggregate function and cast to `amp_varray_typ`:

```
create type emp_varray_typ as varray(50) of varchar2(25);

create table dept (dept_no number, emp_nm_array emp_varray_typ);

create table employee (dept_no, emp_nm) as
select 10, 'Scot' from dual union all
select 10, 'Tiger' from dual union all
select 10, 'John' from dual union all
select 20, 'Cindy' from dual union all
select 20, 'Rock' from dual;
```

```
insert into dept (dept_no, emp_nm_array)
select dept_no, cast(collect(emp_nm) as emp_varray_typ)
from   employee
group by dept_no;
```

More background: [www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306)

Comment: Now we have managed to "collect" multiple values for a DEPTNO into a single column. Is it possible to perform comparison of these columns using SQL Statements?

Example: 
emp_nm_array for Deptno 10 has values {Scot, Tiger, John}
emp_nm_array for Deptno 20 has values {Scot,Tiger}

We need to find out if emp_nm_array for Deptno 20 is present in emp_nm_array for Deptno 10.

Comment: That should work with a nested table collection type (`type x is table of y`) and a submultiset expression. Varrays don't support this.

Comment: Just to add, that's an interesting suggestion. It could be used as an elegant solution for the classic problem of *which customers bought every product*, aka [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).